# Differential equation, Second order linear or non linear.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $y″ + (\sin{x})y′ + (e^x)y =\sinh x$ .

Could anyone tell me about linearity of this equation?
 Should equation  be linear as dependent variable and its derivative not multiply together?  If not, what is the reason for non linearity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here that $y=y(x)$, so the derivatives of $y$ are with respect to $x$. The answer is **yes** this ordinary differential equation is linear. You are exactly right when you say the independent variable is not multiplying it's derivative.

Here is a neat set of notes describing [linearity of ODEs](http://mathstat.slu.edu/~vegaca/linear.pdf), but for ease the main point is:

An ODE for $y=y(x)$ is linear if it can be written in the form:

$a_{n}(x)y^{(n)} + a_{n-1}(x)y^{(n-1)} + \dots + a_{1}(x)y' + a_{0}(x)y = g(x).$

Where the functions $g(x), a_{0}(x), \dots , a_{n}(x)$ can be **any** functions of $x$. Also $y^{(n)}$ denotes the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y$.

I hope this answers your question, thanks.